# A way to match some fields from different pages using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to access **different pages**, insert a name / email in some fields then press a button to submit those fields.

Now, I kind of found a way to match email / name on all pages using webdriver even if they are different in their html structure. I am using the following pieces of code:

```
import logging
from selenium.common.exceptions import ErrorInResponseException, \
    WebDriverException

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
import urlparse
import time
import re


def subscribe(email, name):
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))

    dom = lxml.html.parse('http://muncheye.com')
    url = dom.docinfo.URL
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    failed_urls = []
    i = 0

    to_visit_urls = dom.xpath('//div[@id="right-column"]//a/@href')
    print(len(to_visit_urls))

    """
    Visit each url. Check to be alive. Search form.
    """
    for link in to_visit_urls:
        not_found = False
        name_required = True
        email_required = True
        button_required = True

        dom1 = lxml.html.parse(urlparse.urljoin(url, link))

        submit_url = dom1.xpath(
            '//div[@class="product_info"]//table//tr[7]//td[2]//a/@href')[0]

        if re.match('https?://(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.['
                    '^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}', submit_url):
            time.sleep(10)
            try:
                driver.get(submit_url)
                try:
                    name_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        "//input[@*[contains(translate(., "
                        "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                        "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'name')]]")
                    name_box.click()
                    name_box.clear()
                    name_box.send_keys(email)
                except Exception:
                    not_found = True

                try:
                    email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        "//input[@*[contains(translate(., "
                        "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                        "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'email')]]")
                    email_box.click()
                    email_box.clear()
                    email_box.send_keys(email)
                except Exception:
                    not_found = True

                if not_found:
                    i += 1
                    print "here" + " = " + str(i) + " link = " + str(submit_url)
                    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                            "//input[@type='text']"):
                        if name_required:
                            try:
                                name_box = element.find_element_by_xpath(
                                    ".[@*[contains(translate(., "
                                    "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                    "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'name')]]")
                                name_box.click()
                                name_box.clear()
                                name_box.send_keys(name)
                                name_required = False
                                continue
                            except Exception:
                                pass

                        if email_required:
                            try:
                                email_box = element.find_element_by_xpath(
                                    ".[@*[contains(translate(., "
                                    "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                    "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'email')]]")
                                email_box.click()
                                email_box.clear()
                                email_box.send_keys(email)
                                email_required = False
                                break
                            except Exception:
                                pass

                        if (not name_required) and (not email_required) and (
                                not button_required):
                            break

                for element1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                        "//*[@type[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                        "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'submit']]["
                        "preceding::*[@name[translate(., "
                        "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                        "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ='email' or translate("
                        "., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                        "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ='name']]]"):
                    if button_required:
                        try:
                            button = element1.find_element_by_xpath(
                                "//*[@type[translate(., "
                                "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'submit']]["
                                "preceding::*[@name[translate(., "
                                "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ='email' or "
                                "translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', "
                                "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') "
                                "='name']]]").click()
                            element1.click()
                            element1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                            element1 = False
                            continue
                        except Exception:
                            try:
                                element1.find_element_by_xpath(
                                    "//*[@name='email' or "
                                    "@name='name']//following::*["
                                    "@type='submit']/a").click()
                                element1.click()
                                element1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                                button_required = False
                            except Exception:
                                pass
            except WebDriverException:
                logging.exception('Chrome crashed')
                driver.close()
                driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                to_visit_urls.append(link)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception("Fail here:{0}".format(submit_url))
                failed_urls.append(submit_url)
                pass  # this 'pass' is here because when the script passed
                # from link 33, it gives me fail on all of them

            time.sleep(5)
            print button_required

    return failed_urls


print subscribe('hfbfsdfsdf@freeletter.me', 'hfbfsdfsdf@freeletter.me')
```

Now, I don't know if the problem is from the source code, or webdriver / xpath, but when the button is trying to submit those fields I don't think it's found on the page because I only get 5/6 emails from 100 available links.

Now, the question: can anyone give me a better xpath expression that will be able to press a button / fill name / email fields if the pages are different from one to another ?

Comment: what you are asking is not practical. Xpath is about locating an element based on where it is in HTML structure. If two pages have two different structures, you will have to look for an element with two distinctly different xpath expressions, even this element you are looking for keeps its attributes the same across different pages. One additional suggestion, try CSS selector as well, you may find find element by css selector a better way to locate a webelement.

Comment: @YuZhang i know that this is impractical but I have to do it somehow. And by css selector it's also hard. Let's say that the fields are somehow easier to fill, but what do I have to mess with the most are the buttons. Any alternatives ?

Answer (score -1):

The more proper way to do this is to look for each pair of elements in some specific way based on each page. Do this until you actually find the elements and then do stuff with them. I don't know what the HTML looks like so I can't show you actual code.

Comment: Well, you have them in my code: enter the muncheye site and then on some link from the right column. After this, you will have to enter again the link which is in the upper right corner next to JV page. ( I am doing this for each link on the muncheye page)